# How can I find all lists in a nested list that contains the user input

Tags: python

I have a nested list and trying to use a list comprehension to create a new nested list which contains all lists that contain the year inputted by the user

```
nested_list = [['2021','France'],['2021','Germany'],['2021','Ireland'],['2020','Turkey'],['2020','Germany'],['2020','Ireland'],['2019','Japan'],['2019','USA'],['2019','Ireland']]
```

When the user input a year (2021), I want the output to be a nested list of everything that contains that year

Input: 2021

Output: [[2021,France],[2021,Germany],[2021,Ireland]]

The code I have right now is:

```
myyear = (input('Please enter a year from 2000 and 2021:'))

mydata = [i for sublist in nested_list for i in sublist if myyear in nested_list]
```

When I try to print mydata the list comes out empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string.  You need integers.

```
myyear = int(input('Please enter a year from 2000 to 2021:'))
mydata = [i for i in nested_list if i[0] == myyear]
```